# Return multiple MemoryStream as HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, memorystream

This post might be duplicate but I didn't find a similar post on the stack so I am posting here.
I want to return the list of `MemoryStream` as `HttpResponseMessage`. I have multiple files in a folder I just want to return these files as a `HttpResponseMessage` from web api.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDicomImage(string FolderName)
 {
 try
            {


                    var content = new MultipartContent();
                    MemoryStream dataStream = null;
                    filePathInfo = Directory.GetFiles(FolderName);
                    foreach (var dcm in filePathInfo)
                    {
                        var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dcm);
                        dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);
                        content.Add(dataStream);
                    }
                    httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    httpResponseMessage.Content = content;//new StreamContent(dataStream);
                    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    //httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = bookName;
                    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/dicom");         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)
                };
            }
 }
```

this is my code i dnt understand what going wrong with it. I am not getting multiple MemoryStream for different files.

Comment: An Http message cannot have binary data.  You must use Convert to Base64 string.  I would use FTP which has a binary mode.  FTP is a sub class of HTTP which is meant to transfer files.  FTP in binary mode automatically does the conversion to Base64 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it with the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` from [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package like below:

```
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDicomImage(string FolderName)
    {
        var content = new MultipartContent();
        var filePathInfo = Directory.GetFiles(FolderName);
        var files = new List<FileData>();
        foreach (var dcm in filePathInfo)
        {
            var fileData = new FileData { Content = File.ReadAllBytes(dcm), Name = Path.GetFileName(dcm) };
            files.Add(fileData);
        }
        content.files = files.ToArray();
        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, str);

    }
}

public class MultipartContent
{
    public FileData[] files;
}

public class FileData
{
    public byte[] Content;
    public string Name;
}
```

It is not needed to return stream however. It is enough to return `byte[]` and file name (to make it possible to save file later)

Then you will need to read the response content on client and to deserialize it back to MultipartContent instance

PS Seems that you are trying to send files from the host to the client.
This is not safe since client defines path to be used to get files from. It looks like a security risk even if hosting process do not have permission to read system files. 
Probably you can define certain codes for folders to be mapped on the host side.
Like `documents - ./documents` `images - ./images`. `GetDicomImage` should be modified to accept `documents` `images` codes and to map the code to the physical paths.
It will prevent client from requesting the "c:\" folder (that will not be processed but can be used to DDOS the hosting service.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. having good suggestions write in the post. I am getting the error at here httpResponseMessage.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content); "cannot implicitly convert type string to Httpcontent", So I have change the code like this httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content); does this is correct or not?

Comment: @Pritish yes it is fine, thank you. I will update the answer

Comment: one question How I Can send the multiple memorystream objects. in the HttpResponseMessage

Comment: @Pritish actually you should think how to send several byte arrays in one response. I'v introduced the `MultipartContent` class to hold multiple byte arrays for several files. Then objects are serialized with the  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` that converts several files to the response. MemoryStream object could not be sent with the http response unfortunately